# How can I allocate more memory on my server?

Tags: memory, apache2, php7, outofmemoryerror

I am pulling down real estate properties from the Toronto Real Estate Board and I am using a LAMP stack with [PHRETS](https://github.com/troydavisson/PHRETS) on a **2GB Digital Ocean VPS**. When I pull down the properties, I run some processes on them before saving them to a database. I have a cron job that runs the script every hour. Sometimes, the script runs flawlessly. Other times, I get this error, often within the first minute:

`PHP Fatal error:  Out of memory (allocated 131076096) (tried to allocate 12288 bytes) in /var/www/mysite.com/vendor/joshcam/mysqli-database-class/MysqliDb.php on line 1511`

I've updated my `php.ini` file with `memory_limit = 1500M`

I am quite new to all of this but I am under the impression this should allow a script to allocate 1500MB, or 1.5GB of memory.

The error seems to be saying that the script tried to allocate `12288 bytes` of a possible `131076096 bytes`, but that doesn't add up, does it? How can I fix this? Do I need to upgrade my server or should 2GB of RAM be enough? Is there something I am missing?

Comment: Which php.ini did you update?  Some distros have multiple copies.

Comment: You should consider optimizing your cron to not use as much RAM. Often, this can be done by putting something that's repeatedly executing (via a loop, for example) into a function so its variables get cleaned up at the end of each iteration.

Answer (score 2):

> I've updated my php.ini file with `memory_allowed = 1500M`

There's [no such setting](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php). The setting is named `memory_limit`. Be sure to restart your webserver (or PHP-FPM if you're using that) after making the change.

Comment: Whoops. Yeah, that is what I had on the server, but typed it out wrong in my question. Thanks for mentioning that though.

Comment: @MichaelLynch Use `phpinfo()` on a test PHP file to make sure you've got the right `php.ini` (it will output which ones it's looking in) and be certain you restarted the webserver (and PHP-FPM if you're on that).

Comment: Yep. All good. I've got the `phpinfo()` running and I can see `1500M`. I've also restarted the server.

Comment: @MichaelLynch Can you do `php -i` via the CLI too? Sometimes cron (as it runs on CLI) uses a different `php.ini`.

Comment: I ran `php -i` and I see `memory_limit => -1 => -1` under Core. I presume the `-1` is in place of `1500M`, which is what I set.

Answer (score 1):

Your PHP warning means that your script tried to allocate 12288 **above** the allowed maximum (default 128 MB).

You can raise the default maximum, but you need to be careful to not overallocated memory.

Comment: "It does not mean that all memory is allocated by this single script, rather than the PHP module itself is using all its allowed memory." This is *not* true. http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.memory-limit "This sets the maximum amount of memory in bytes that **a script** is allowed to allocate."

Comment: @ceejayoz you are right, I incorrectly remembered that. I've edited my answer, thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: So my maximum is set to `1500M`...does that mean it requires `12288` bytes more than that? Each time the script runs, there is a different number of properties, so I'd expect that number to change each hour, but it doesn't. Also, what is `131076096` referring to?

Comment: `131076096` is 128 MB. Your script is allocating `131076096 + 12288` bytes, which is forbidden by your current PHP settings.